# PHP unique array and overwrite values

Tags: php

I have this array

```
$finalArray = array (
  0 => 
  array (        
    'deviceMacAddress' => 'd4:fc:9b:81:87:32',
    'pressure' => 1015.12,
    'temperature' => 22.296875,
    'co2' => '',
    'voc' => '',
    'humidity' => '',
    'light' => 1,
    'pm1' => '',
    'pm25' => '',
    'pm10' => '',
    'timestamp' => 1644917014994,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (        
    'deviceMacAddress' => 'c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33',
    'pressure' => '',
    'temperature' => '',
    'co2' => '20',
    'voc' => '10',
    'humidity' => '',
    'light' => '50',
    'pm1' => '',
    'pm25' => '',
    'pm10' => '',
    'timestamp' => 1644917018996,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'deviceMacAddress' => 'c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33',
    'pressure' => '',
    'temperature' => '',
    'co2' => '10',
    'voc' => '',
    'humidity' => 32,
    'light' => '',
    'pm1' => '',
    'pm25' => '',
    'pm10' => '',
    'timestamp' => 1644917018997,
  ),
);
```

I want to get the unique array by deviceMacAddress from it. as you can notice there are two device with macAddress c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33
I can get the unique array easily . but i want to override the value if macaddress matches and get the latest one.

so i want my array to look like this

```
$finalArray = array (
  0 => 
  array (        
    'deviceMacAddress' => 'd4:fc:9b:81:87:32',
    'pressure' => 1015.12,
    'temperature' => 22.296875,
    'co2' => '',
    'voc' => '',
    'humidity' => '',
    'light' => 1,
    'pm1' => '',
    'pm25' => '',
    'pm10' => '',
    'timestamp' => 1644917014994,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (        
    'deviceMacAddress' => 'c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33',
    'pressure' => '',
    'temperature' => '',
    'co2' => '10',
    'voc' => '10',
    'humidity' => '32',
    'light' => '50',
    'pm1' => '',
    'pm25' => '',
    'pm10' => '',
    'timestamp' => 1644917018997,
  )
  
);
```

Here I could get unique array
https://3v4l.org/4UHYC

Comment: Your question leaves out enough details to make it very hard to answer. I figured out you want to combine all sub-arrays with the same Mac address. By "get the latest one" it seems you mean "latest in time based on the timestamp value". What I still cannot figure out is how the timestamp of Mac 'c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33' becomes 1644917018996? In my code it ends up as 1644917018997 unless I make an exception for the timestamp and use the oldest value.

Comment: The second array was a sample how i wanted. so timestamp could be the latest as you mentions. 
With the help of @nice_dev I managed to make it worked.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You will have to run another foreach inside the current foreach to check with empty values and skip them and override them if they are not.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$data = [];

foreach($finalArray as $value){
    $data[ $value['deviceMacAddress'] ] = $data[ $value['deviceMacAddress'] ] ?? $value;
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
        if($v == '') continue;
        $data[ $value['deviceMacAddress'] ][$k] = $v;
    }
}


print_r($data);
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/916847d76c7a1ce70e05f6e24e91f8facc9cdf17)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    [ 'deviceMacAddress' => 'd4:fc:9b:81:87:32', 'timestamp' => 1644917014994 ],
    [ 'deviceMacAddress' => 'c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33', 'timestamp' => 1644917018996 ],
    [ 'deviceMacAddress' => 'c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33', 'timestamp' => 1644917018997 ],
    [ 'deviceMacAddress' => 'c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33', 'timestamp' => 1644917018995 ],
];

$result = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
  $ip = $item['deviceMacAddress'];
  if (isset($result[$ip]['timestamp']) === false || $item['timestamp'] > $result[$ip]['timestamp']) {
    $result[$ip] = $item;
  }
}
```

Since this solution creates a result array with the IPs as key:

```
Array
(
    [d4:fc:9b:81:87:32] => Array
        (
            [deviceMacAddress] => d4:fc:9b:81:87:32
            [timestamp] => 1644917014994
        )

    [c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33] => Array
        (
            [deviceMacAddress] => c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33
            [timestamp] => 1644917018997
        )

)
```

... you can use array_values to get an indexed array, if that is desired:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [deviceMacAddress] => d4:fc:9b:81:87:32
            [timestamp] => 1644917014994
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [deviceMacAddress] => c8:7a:6c:09:eb:33
            [timestamp] => 1644917018997
        )

)
```